# How to alter attributes in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to alter options of a widget after creating/drawing it? I can't seem to find any way to do so. What I'm currently aiming for is altering the fg of a Label once its temp0 textvariable is >= 50.

This code is part of a bigger program, so I didn't want to put all of that here, since the essential part is that I am not sure how to change the fg (i.e. font color) for that Label once I get the b[0] value and find out that it is above 50. Is the `self.t0.config(fg="red")` the proper syntax for that?

```
 class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

    #live updating TkInter variables    
        self.temp0 = DoubleVar()

        frame = Frame(master)
        self.t0 = Label(frame, fg="blue", textvariable=self.temp0,font=(20)).grid(row=2, column=0)
        frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def start(self):
        # calculates temperature
        self.temp0.set(b[0])

        # changes color of text to red if temp >= 50
        if b[0] >= 50:
            self.t0.config(fg="red")
```

Comment: N.B.: When you do `self.t0 = Label(...).grid(...)`, you are setting `self.t0` to None, since that's what `grid(...)` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that works.  You can use either:

```
self.t0.config(fg="red")
```

or:

```
self.t0["fg"] = "red"
```

Both methods do the same thing, so you can choose what you want.

Also, to get everything working, you will want to make this line of code:

```
self.t0 = Label(frame, fg="blue", textvariable=self.temp0,font=(20)).grid(row=2, column=0)
```

into two lines:

```
self.t0 = Label(frame, fg="blue", textvariable=self.temp0,font=(20))
self.t0.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Now, `self.t0` will point to the label like it should and not the return value of `.grid`, which is `None`.

Comment: I was having other issues with setting up options for the Label, and I think that separating that line into two will fix it. I'll try those suggestions out later this week and update here. Thank you for the help!

Comment: That fix worked, and the program is working as I want it to. Thank you again!